# How to configure AWS for secure video storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am pretty new to aws. I want to store my video files in s3 bucket and host them on my website using cloudfront. Users should be able to download videos only after logging onto my website.
How do i go about implementing this? Since i am new to aws, a tutorial link would be very helpful. Thank You.

Also if you could suggest other cheaper but reliable CDNs for video files, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict your Amazon S3 content to accept requests only from Amaozn CloudFront and also use signed, temporary URLS for content delivery, thus serving private content through CloudFront.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html